# How to update cells in a google spreadsheet with python’s gspread wks.update_cells

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a doc in GS  with automatically uploaded data  with numeric values in  string format. 
In all cells there is a mark so I can turn strings into numbers by removing it.

[image]

It works successfully  when I use the gspread  method for updating one cell:  `wks.update_acell("B7", str(1939.0).replace("'"," "))`

But I want to change all cells in a range with wks.update_cells.

In official gspread docs there is an example:

```
cell_list = wks.range('A1:C7')

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = 'O_o'

# Update in batch
wks.update_cells(cell_list)
```

In this form it works but  in my case with   `cell.value = str.replace("'","")`  I  get error:

```
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I think  I need to put smth in parentheses str().replace – but  don't understand what… Can anyone help me, please?

PS 
The full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
from file4dir1 import rep


    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
    pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr',False)
    pd.set_option('max_colwidth',-1)

    mytoken='***'
    project = '***'

    DateFrom="2019-12-01"
    DateTo="2019-12-31"

    data=rep(mytoken,project,DateFrom,DateTo)

    file=open("cashe3.csv","w")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    f=pd.read_csv("cashe3.csv", header=1, sep=' ',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

import googleapiclient.discovery
import argparse
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools  

    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "myGSapp4.json"
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Report'
    credential_path = 'sheets.googleapis.com-report.json'

from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.file import Storage   

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, parents=[tools.argparser])
    flags = parser.parse_args([])
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http


import gspread
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g     

    spreadsheet_key = '***'
    wks_name = 'Sheet0'
    d2g.upload(f, spreadsheet_key, wks_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
```

#the row and column indexes just for example

```
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    wks_name = gc.open_by_key('***').get_worksheet(0)
    cell_list = wks_name.range('E7:E13')
    requests = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "findReplace": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 'Sheet0',
                        "startRowIndex": 7,
                        "endRowIndex": 13,
                        "startColumnIndex": 5,
                        "endColumnIndex": 5
                    },
                    "find": "^'",
                    "searchByRegex": True,
                    "includeFormulas": True,
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    wks_name.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try in this way, it should work:

```
cell_list = wks.range('A1:C7')

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = 'O_o'

# Update in batch
wks.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

What you were missing was: `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED'`

For any problem, please have a look to the
[API Reference](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.update)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Sheetfu library](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu) instead and its Table module for that particular case.

```
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp
from sheetfu import Table

spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp('path/to/secret.json').open_by_id('<spreadsheet id>')
data_range = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('sheet name').get_data_range()

table = Table(data_range)

for item in table:
    impression_value = item.get_field_value('Impressions')
    if impression_value[0] = "'":
        impression_value = impression_value[1:]
        item.get_set_value('Impressions', impression_value)

table.commit()
```

This should do the trick.

You can also cast the impression value to float before sending it to the sheet, it would then be handled and put as a number in the sheet.

The `set` method does not actually make any changes. It only store the request at Table level. This is for performance purposes to avoid making a request to API on every row that needs to be updated. Instead we create a batch of requests, that are sent all together to Spreadsheet API using `table.commit()`.

Comment: Thank you,Philippe Oger, unfortunately this way  doesn 't work in my case either. I believe there is some kind of curse hanging over my table))  or  I'm making some stupid elusive mistake.   ''You can also cast the impression value to float before sending it to the sheet" - I tried diffrent ways to do it but changes are only applied at dataframe and not transferred to the sheets

Comment: @DaryaKibireva did you make sure to commit the table in your code? If you do not commit, changes will not be pushed to the sheet.

Comment: The code looks fine. I'm afraid I can't help more without looking at your spreadsheet, which I understand is not necessary possible. Maybe the character is not exactly the one you think: copy/paste the character you want to delete from the spreadsheet onto the code, and see if you have the same result. If you print the impression value, can you still see the first character?

Answer (score 0):

- You want to remove the single quote `'` at the top of value in each cell using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In order to remove the single quote `'` at the top of value in each cell, in this answer, I use "FindReplaceRequest" with the method of `batch_update` of gspread. Using "FindReplaceRequest", the values in the range are replaced.

I thought that this way is more simpler. So I proposed this.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "###"  # Please set the sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "findReplace": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 7,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 3
                },
                "find": "^'",
                "searchByRegex": True,
                "includeFormulas": True,
                "replacement": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(requests)
```

- In this case, the values of cells "A1:C7" are replaced. This is from the script in your question.

#### Note:

- For example, if you want to replace the values in all cells at one sheet, please modify `requests` as follows.

  ```
  requests = {
      "requests": [
          {
              "findReplace": {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "find": "^'",
                  "searchByRegex": True,
                  "includeFormulas": True,
                  "replacement": ""
              }
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike! You understand me right, thank you! I tried your code but  have some problem: when I repeat  your code I get such an error:  module 'oauth2client.client' has no attribute 'open_by_key' . What i miss?

Comment: @Darya Kibireva Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from `module 'oauth2client.client' has no attribute 'open_by_key'`, I cannot correctly image your script. For example, `client` is `client = gspread.authorize(credentials)`. How about this? If this didn't resolve your issue, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide your current whole script for replicating the issue? By this I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I'm sorry for delay in answering
i did it with gspread.authorize(credentials),  got update confirmation:
https://www.screencast.com/t/BOGF6tirCKC  but nothing has changed:
 https://www.screencast.com/t/qJJsgbyGLEC (no, i didn't mix up the key or id...) what else could be wrong?

Comment: @Darya Kibireva Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your script in your shared image, I could understand about the issue. I think that in the gridrange of your request body is not correct. If you want to reflect this request body to the cells of `F8:F13`, please modify `range` to `"range": {"sheetId": sheetId,"startRowIndex": 7,"endRowIndex": 13,"startColumnIndex": 5,"endColumnIndex": 6}`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) Please try the script again after you modified it.

Comment: @Darya Kibireva By the way, in your request body, you are using `"find": "4"`. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. If you want to remove the single quote, please modify to `"find": "^'"`.

Comment: of course I tried with  "find": "^'"  too, but it also  doesn't work in my case unfortunately :(  But thank you anyway for trying to help me, I didn't know about method  findReplace  - will use in  other situations

Comment: @Darya Kibireva Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I would like to resolve your issue. But in my environment, I could confirm that the script works. So in order to correctly understand about `it also doesn't work in my case`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your whole script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can do, please add them to your question. Of course, please remove your personal information. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tainake, I added the whole script and this is the sheet  https://www.screencast.com/t/CIkEnV9kZBi  Thank you for your patience and desire to help =)

Comment: @Darya Kibireva Thank you for replying and adding the information. When I saw your script, I could notice the following 2 points. 1. In your script, I can see `wks_name = 'Sheet0'`. In this case, you use `Sheet0` as the sheet name. But for the request body of `update_cells`, it seems that you are using `Sheet0` as the sheet ID. In my sample script, the sheet ID is retrieved from the sheet name. By this, gspread cannot find the sheet.

Comment: @Darya Kibireva 2. About the `range`, it seems that this also doesn't reflect [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701452/how-to-update-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-with-python-s-gspread-wks-update-cel/59702192?noredirect=1#comment105701512_59702192). It seems that your request body is not changed from https://www.screencast.com/t/BOGF6tirCKC I would like to resolve your issue. But unfortunately, your script doesn't reflect my answer. By this, I think that your issue is not resolved. If you cannot understand about my English, please tell me. I'm worry about this.