# APIError code 400 gspread: Infinity and New Lines?

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to use the worksheet .update method to update a new and an existing spreadsheet, but I cannot make sense of this APIError I am getting and what needs to be fixed.

The error thrown is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-f622d98bfbfc>", line 38, in <module>
    worksheetP.update(

  File "C:\Users\Vincent\anaconda3\envs\mlb_analysis\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 592, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Vincent\anaconda3\envs\mlb_analysis\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1123, in update
    response = self.spreadsheet.values_update(

  File "C:\Users\Vincent\anaconda3\envs\mlb_analysis\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 236, in values_update
    r = self.client.request('put', url, params=params, json=body)

  File "C:\Users\Vincent\anaconda3\envs\mlb_analysis\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 76, in request
    raise APIError(response)

APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n 2.0, "", 3, "", 1, Infinity, 17.0, "", \n                    ^', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

Here is the link to the code I am trying to run here, it is pulling down some baseball stats from sportsreference: https://github.com/raiavincent/MLB-Analysis/blob/main/getPlayerStatsMLB.py

Looking at the code you can see I have tried a number of fixes already, which I've gotten mainly from the gspread issues page.

If anyone can point me in the right direction of what is causing this error or how to fix it, that would be amazing.

Comment: my guess is the error is from here `self.client.request('put', url, params=params, json=body)`. Your `body` variable is not valid. Also do you have access to the googlesheets from the app? YOu need to be authorized for the google sheets api

Comment: Yes. I have access to the sheet. In the code I’m both pulling from an existing sheet and making a new one. 

I understand there is a variable that’s not valid, I just can’t figure out what variable I have to get rid of and what that variable is.

Comment: It’s whatever is the 'body' variable is. You may need to debug and jump into the gspread functions to see where it came from. I can do it, but will have to wait until later

Comment: Right, I get that, it's just I have tried to drop so many variables from the dataframe, like infinity, na, NaN, etc, and it still is throwing me the error.

Comment: Ya I’ll take a look when I get a chance and see if I can narrow down the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a fix for my issue, for anyone having the same problem.

Basically, I made the whole dataframe a string as the first step.

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

Then, I used requests as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701452/how-to-update-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-with-python-s-gspread-wks-update-cel) from Tanaike to remove any ^ in the sheet, therefore unstringing any numbers.