# Gspread append is not removing the single quote

Tags: gspread

I have switched to using gspread instead of pure google sheets api.  Before i formatted my input into a json body but now i send the list direct.  The append works without an error but the first item has an extra single quote on the beginning of the date.

I fell like im following the example to the letter so it seems like a bug but i wanted to ask here first just in case i'm doing something silly.

> values = ['2021-08-11', '-', '-', 372, 373, 'Brayden', 'ChrisT',
> 'Chris', 'Dida', 'Darren', 'Ferdi', 'Bernard', 'Cal', 'Gavin',
> 'Conor']
>
> ws.append_row(values)

First item in sheet: '2021-08-11

Originally using the pure api i was formatting the body as follows but as i understand it with gspread i should just be able to send the list.

> ```
>     body = {
>         'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
>         'values': [
>             google_output,
>         ],
>         }
> ```

The same seems to happen if i update instead of append:

> ws.update(range, values, major_dimension='ROWS')

Im using version 4.0.0 of gspread and here is the guide im following:

> (method) append_row: (values, value_input_option='RAW',
> insert_data_option=None, table_range=None) -> Any Adds a row to the
> worksheet and populates it with values.
>
> Widens the worksheet if there are more values than columns.
>
> :param list values: List of values for the new row. :param str
> value_input_option: (optional) Determines how the input data
> should be interpreted. See ValueInputOption_ in the Sheets API reference. :param str insert_data_option: (optional) Determines how
> the input data
> should be inserted. See InsertDataOption_ in the Sheets API reference. :param str table_range: (optional) The A1 notation of a
> range to search
> for a logical table of data. Values are appended after the last row of the table. Examples: A1 or B2:D4

Comment: Found the answer here in the end. I needed USER_ENTERED https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701452/how-to-update-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-with-python-s-gspread-wks-update-cel

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with gspread itself. I encountered this problem myself and according to this [thread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/524) not only us. In this thread they suggest to add
`value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'`
(so that your code looks like this:

```
values = ['2021-08-11', '-', '-', 372, 373, 'Brayden', 'ChrisT', 'Chris', 'Dida', 'Darren', 'Ferdi', 'Bernard', 'Cal', 'Gavin', 'Conor']

ws.append_row(values, value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED')
```

)
in order to remove that single quote. It worked for me and I hope that it works for you as well